# Does combining tools have a maximum durability limit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I saw [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/57190/57625) which explains when combining items, the result will be:

> Tool 1 durability + Tool 2 durability + (Maximum durability/10) = Resulting durability

However, it mentions a maximum durability but doesn't explain if this limit can be hit again. For example, if I combine two pickaxes which have been used once each, will the result be:

> Axe 1 durability + Axe 2 durability + (Maximum durability/10) = Maximum durability (100%)

Or:

> Axe 1 durability (99%) + Axe 2 durability (99%) + (Maximum durability/10) (10%) = 208% durability

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The durability when repairing (combining) tools is capped at 100%. Combining two tools with 99% durability and combining two with 45% durability will both give you a tool that is exactly the same as a new one (of the same material, of course).